# Select documents in collection that match foreign key value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB aggregate to grab some documents in collection `Events` that reference the collection `Program` with the constraint of `Program.type`

Events

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   programId: ObjectId
}
```

Programs

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   type: "Type A"
}
```

The pseudo sql-like query would be like `select * from events where event.id = 1234 and where program.type = "Type A"`

I've got this and I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {_id: id}
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'programs',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'programId',
        as: 'program'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$program'
  },
  {
    $match: {'program.type': 'Type A'}
  }
]
```

I actually thought this worked but it failed when I tried different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, this query:

```sql
select * from events where event.id = 1234 and where program.type = "Type A"
```

Is this query:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "programs",
      "as": "programs",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$type",
                "A"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Where:

- select * -> is get all fields by default in mongo db
- from events -> `db.events.aggregate`
- where event.id = 1234 -> is the `$match`
- program.type = "Type A" -> `$lookup` with pipeline where `{"$eq": ["$type","A"]}`

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eUJy_9dfQm-)